# Elasticsearch rails search in collection

Tags: ruby-on-rails, elasticsearch, rubygems

Is there a way to search in collection of a given model?

I use elasticsearch_rails gem.

What I mean is that I have a product, and I want to return that product with a specific variant in it (product has many variants).

For example I want to do sth like this:

```
@product = Product.__elasticsearch__.search(query: {
        match: {
            slug: params[:slug],
            "variants.id": params[:variant_id]
        }
    })
```

What I want to get is product with only one variant specified in variants id.

Is that possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I used inner hits to get something like this.